# Simplify 4y+5x if y+x=m

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any way of simplifying this further? Very basic algebra but im having a blank

I have 2 equations, 4y+5x  and y+x=m, can you combine them to get this in terms of m?

Comment: actually you have one equation, since 4x+5y is not an equation, is just an expression

Comment: Apologies, any expression i have is =0

Comment: Haha, no problem, do not apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is. It seems the best you can do is something like $$4y+5x = 4(x+y)+x = 4m+x$$

Comment: Thanks i wasn't sure it was possible but wanted to check.

Comment: No problem. If you had a third equation, you would be able to do what you are trying to do. In general, if you have $n$ unknowns (in your case you had three) you need $n$ equations to solve the system